# center block CSS

Tags: css, block, centering

Working on a wordpress site.  Having trouble aligning a product category block.  First it would only display 4 products when per. row if i set to 5, 3 if set to 4, etc.  I fixed that, something to do with margins. The category block is slightly off center, really annoying.  Below is some code for the block that i used.  Any help would be appreciated.
https://rightwaycrane.staging.wpengine.com/pendant-control-stations/

```
.page-id-1608 .wc-block-grid__product {
margin: 0;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Flexbox? That is a much better way to organize elements vs. hard coding margin & padding https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I looked a flexbox, forgot about it honestly.  I am new to this and looked at the code tried to implement but stuck.  Time to learn this is short.  This code below didnt work tried to force it with !important, I know not good practice, but didnt work anyway;
.page-id-1608 .wc-block-grid__product {
 display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
 align-content: center !important;
 border: 2px solid #182c6d;
}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following styles are causing your content to not be centered correctly.

```css
.content-part-left {
  padding: 50px 30px 20px 98px;
}

.content-part-left ul {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.content-part-left ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

If you remove or adjust it should resolve the center on page issue.

```css
.content-part-left {
  padding: 50px 30px 20px;
}

.content-part-left ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I put in your code above to the specific page but it moved everything to the extreme left.  I found my own work around that centered the category, kinda of a hack but it worked.  Ignore the border just there for affect;
.page-id-1608 .wc-block-grid__product {
 margin: -4px;
 border: 2px solid #182c6d; 
}